# How to download marker from GMLib to file

Tags: delphi, gmlib

There is Delphi GMLIB application with TGMMap and TGMMarker. How to download marker image from TGMMarker to file ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do. Can you explain better?

Comment: I'm looking for any method like this: GMMarker1[0].SaveToFile('Boooo.png');

Comment: but what do you want to save? the marker image? If it is an URL, you can use Indy components to download it. If this is an image on local PC, you already have the image